# Different behavior for decimal.ToString

Tags: c#, decimal, tostring

I've encountered a very strange behavior of `decimal.ToString`:
First Case:
[image]

You can see that variable `ValueFloat = 9` and `ValueFloat.Value.ToString("G") = "9"`.

Second Case:

[image]

You can see that variable `ValueFloat = 9` and `ValueFloat.Value.ToString("G") = "9.000000000000000".`

Now, how is it possible? Variable ValueFloat has the same value in both cases.

I had an assumption that it might be connected to culture, but in both cases the code runs on my local machine, which has the same culture obviously.

Comment: Decimal tracks significant digits.

Comment: what is `DataType` of `Value` ?

Comment: ValueFloat is Nullable<decimal>.
So, .Value is a Decimal.

Comment: Sunil - it seems to me that `Value` is `string`. @DimaK - Is `ValueFloat` the same `DataType` in both instances? i.e. `decimal`?

Comment: public Nullable<decimal> ValueFloat

in both cases.

Comment: @DimaK Are both of these code blocks in the same method/class?

Comment: Yes, it is the only breakpoint I have in my entire solution.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight has stated, this could be to do with performing calculations on `Value` before the second code block - is this the case?

Comment: I will check this out tomorrow and update everyone. I'm not sure about the calculations, but it is possible. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could happen if the value was a result of an arithmetic operation involving significant digits after the dot. Here is an example:

```
decimal a = 9;
decimal b = 1.23456789M;
decimal c = 10.23456789M;
decimal d = c-b; // The result is 9
Console.WriteLine("Values are the same: {0}", a == d);
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G"));
```

Running the above [produces](http://ideone.com/i7yrSV) the output below:

```
Values are the same: True
9
9.00000000
```

Comment: We all learn something new, every day! Quick question @dasblinkenlight - could this behaviour be happening as a result of the `ToString()` method being called, also? Or would you speculate that OP is most likely doing calculations on the `decimal` before the second output?

Comment: @GeoffJames I would be surprised if `ToString` caused any detectable change to the thing it converts to string. In fact, I'd report this to Microsoft as a bug. I think OP's two values are obtained through different code paths.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight - it was just more of a sanity check for me! I would also imagine they are referenced through different paths - I did ask as a comment, but got a rather ambiguous answer :(